# Triple integral with exponentiation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to integrate

```
Integrate[x*E^(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1], {x,0,1}, {y,0,1}, {z,0,1}]
```

However Mathematica gives me

```
E*Integrate[x*DawsonF[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, Sqrt[1 - x^2]}]
```

instead of a closed form. Using `NIntegrate` does match numerically the actual answer, `Pi/8`. How can I evaluate this integral without using spherical coordinates? I've tried with `Assumptions -> x>=0 && y>=0 && z>=0`, but that does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
Integrate[
 x*E^(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) Boole[x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0],
 {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[]]
(*  π/8  *)
```

Also this:

```
Integrate[Abs@x*E^(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[]]/8
(*  π/8  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0,
   {x, y, z}];

Pi*RootApproximant[
  NIntegrate[
    x*E^(x^2 + y^2 + z^2),
    {x, y, z} ∈ rgn]/
   Pi]

(*  π/8  *)
```